# Updated PPA for Gparted

Tags: 13.04, ppa, gparted

I am looking for a PPA that has an updated version of GPARTED. The one in the official repositories is very old (Version 0.12.1). Since then, there has been 10 new versions. The last one was the 0.16 that came out yesterday.

Is there a PPA that offers the latest GPARTED, specially because of the fixes it hovers and new file systems it supports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GetDeb](http://www.getdeb.net/) has the latest packages.
To use the repository, follow [the instructions on their website](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/12.10/#how_to_install).
After you added the repository, run `sudo apt-get update` from terminal to make sure you can install packages from there. Now you can [install the newest version of GParted](http://www.getdeb.net/software/gparted).

*Please note that GetDeb is an unofficial source. Although they test the packages before release, their testing is not nearly as strict as the official repositorys. Therefore, packages **might** be broken and there is a very small chance of seriously breaking things.*

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the fact that I am using 13.04. GetDeb does not yet support this version.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to wait a little until it's supported, set up your own PPA (you can import the code from GIT or SourceForge and have it built automatically) or compile it manually on a regular basis.
(You could also autobuild it on your local machine using a shell script or something and a cronjob.)